# How do I list properties with `systemctl`?

Tags: systemd, cgroups

You can set a property with `systemctl` using,

```
set-property UNIT PROPERTY=VALUE... Sets one or more properties of a unit
```

But how do I find the properties that can be set? I'm looking for a `list-property` or `get-properties` but I don't see it. The only command in `man systemctl` under "Unit Commands" with the name *"property"* is `set-property`. This question is prompted by [this video](https://youtu.be/mkhyIgEiQWU?t=152), the author shows an example of using the cgroup to limit cpu access by setting the property called `CPUQuota` with `systemctl`, but what other properties can I set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see the list of properties with `systemctl show`, such as

```
systemctl show user-1000.slice
```

However, this only lists the currently-set properties of the unit. To find what properties are available, you can check the `systemd` manual pages. The `CPUQuota` property is part of the `resource-control` settings, which are documented in `systemd.resource-control(5)` which can be read online many places, but my personal go-to is FreeDesktop's mirror of the man-pages [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html). Alternatively, you can use the `man` command, if the systemd manual pages are installed, like this

```
man 5 systemd.resource-control
```

Other `systemd` manuals can be found using the `apropos` command like so

```
# The ending '.' is helpful since many manuals reference systemd
apropos systemd\.
```